# The redirect_uri URL must be absolute error

Tags: c#, facebook

what i am trying to do is redirecting the user if it's access token is expired i am doing this using my localhost like this :

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
           "client_id=" + "{507061112747022}" +
           "&redirect_uri=" + "{http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx}");
```

but the error is occurring saying `The redirect_uri URL must be absolute error` what would be the problem ? and how can i fix it ( i am using c# as language )

Comment: This question maybe able to help 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992958/the-redirect-uri-url-must-be-absolute-facebook-login-php-sdk

Comment: i checked that link before i post my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the curly braces.

Url encode the redirect URI.

```
Response.Redirect("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +
   "client_id=507061112747022" +
   "&redirect_uri=" + 
   Uri.EscapeDataString("http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx"));
```

Comment: your solution worked but i get this now : API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.

Comment: This is a separate issue. Most likely your Facebook app settings need changing. IIRC, testing on localhost with Facebook is problematic. Don't working solutions usually get upvotes? ;)

Comment: can u tell me how to fix this issue ? what url should i fix in my application configuration for this to work ?

Comment: I'd probably create an alias for 127.0.0.1 in my \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file (something like `mylocaldomain.net`) and use that as the registered callback url for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to set the string as a lit

with appending @ to the start of your response.redirect

so it would look like

```
Response.Redirect(@"https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +    
       "client_id=" + "{507061112747022}" +
       "&redirect_uri=" + "{http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx}");
```

as Spender said below you could also encode as a URI

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?" +    
           "client_id=" + "507061112747022" +
           "&redirect_uri=" + "http://localhost:63695/FacebookChatApi/Default.aspx");
```