# "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute" error on Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

EDIT: I have `http://www.example.com` (example being my live site) as the **Site URL** under basic settings. I also have `www.example.com` and `example.com`under **App Domains**.

The error I'm getting is:

> The redirect_uri URL must be absolute

My code breaks when I try to login. Here's my code for the `getLoginUrl()`:

```
<?php

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'MYAPPID',
        'app_secret' => 'MYAPPSECRET',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.5',
    ]);

    $redirectURI = 'http://example.com/login-callback.php';
    $encodedRedirectURI = urlencode($redirectURI);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(
            array(
                'scope' => 'ads_management,read_insights',
                'redirect_uri' => $encodedRedirectURI
            )
        );

    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';

?>
```

Why is this error happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is this error happening?

Because you are URL-encoding the URL, before passing it to the `getLoginUrl` method.

The SDK takes care of that internally - so now you have a URL that has been URL-encoded *twice*, and that makes it unrecognizable as a valid, absolute URL.

So just pass the URL to that method *without* applying any extra encoding.

---

Edit: Additionally, the method `getLoginUrl` expects *two* parameters - first the redirect URI, and then the scope as the second one - not both as *one* array.

```
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl(
    $redirectURI,
    array('ads_management', 'read_insights')
);
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, but can you please give me a code example of what this should be instead of what I have?

Comment: Actually, your parameters were wrong in more than one regard - see my edit, please.

Answer (score 0):

You will also need to add your redirect URL (http://example.com/login-callback.php) as "Valid OAuth redirect URI" in the advanced settings of your facebook app (https://developers.facebook.com/apps).

Comment: I'm not seeing this input anywhere, "Valid OAuth redirect URI". Where do you go to edit this specifically?

Comment: have you added your domain on the App Domains list?

Comment: Have you added the example.com as Website Platform in your Facebook app?

Comment: It won't let me add example.com/login-callback.php

Comment: Under "Tell us about your website - Site URL:" in choose your platform, I have it set as "http://www.example.com/"