# Facebook PHP SDK - "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using PHP Graph SDK to simplify logins to my site using Facebook.

The problem I'm getting is the error message after successfully logging into Facebook: "The redirect_uri URL must be absolute".
I've trawled the web (didn't find a solution) and added the redirect URL as "Valid OAuth redirect URI" at Facebook Dev Apps.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ILkp.png)

But the error persists.

Here is the code:

```
  $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID,
    'app_secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET,
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
    ]);

  $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
  $permissions = ['public_profile', 'email', 'user_location']; 
  $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.example.com/login_facebook.php', $permissions);
```

The full URL generated by the SDK is:
https://www.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth?client_id=9999999999999999&state=9999999999999999999999b&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.5.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Flogin_facebook.php&scope=email

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The image didn't work - please can you amend it to show us what it shows (unless it is a private url)

Comment: Please go through this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993022/4610417

Comment: @deffrin-joseph - I am using a complete URL (example.com) which is the LIVE_URL constant I am using there (see my inline comment). I've edited the code so that it's clearer. Antony - fixed the image